# Grails: Trying to use tablesorter

Tags: jquery, grails, tablesorter

This is probably a really dumb question but I am trying to use table sorter with a Grails project and I have the jquery.tablesorter.js file copied into the 'js' directory of my Grails project and have my columns now sortable on clicking but I was wondering about all the other stuff that comes with table sorter like widgets and the css themes. In order to get those do I just keep following the same pattern of adding files to my project i.e. keep adding to my Grails project's 'js' and 'css' directory? I was worried about what directory paths need to be preserved to get theme and widget functionality. Any advice greatly appreciated. I wasn't able to find specific installation instructions for the themes ad widgets anywhere. Basically, I'd like to get maximum functionality out of the plugin but do not know where to place some of the additional css and images files exactly especially as I noticed an 'images' directory withing the 'css' directory and I already have an 'images' directory in my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to locate some information on using the tablesorter that might be helpful.

if you add this to your page header you should get the functionality of tablesort with widgets and themes.

```
<!-- ui theme stylesheet - contents shown below -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme.jui.css">
<!-- jQuery UI theme (cupertino example here) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">

<!-- tablesorter plugin -->
<script src="../js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<!-- tablesorter widget file - loaded after the plugin -->
<script src="../js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
```

Full demo at 
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-ui-theme.html

Comment: Wow, thanks for replying after all this time. I din't even remember the question :)